# I want to add all the names of the files in a specific folder to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I want to add the names of all the files in a specific folder to a list how can i do that? the pathway is from dropbox -> a folder called 'UMM' -> a folder called '2018' could someone help me with the code on this. I have tried using os.walk() but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: look at `os.listdir`  It does just this.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir.  You should be able to just give it the folder you want the directory from.  If it doesn't answer your question, post your code and the error(s) you are getting.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

import os
path = "Desktop/Electricity Markets/Program"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

Comment: I don't think that is a good path.  Try using the fully qualified path from the root.  If you aren't sure, open a terminal or ipython window in that folder and type pwd to get the present working directory.  Or on windows you can also shift-right click on the folder and select "copy as path" which will give you the full path.  Try that

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: In specific, if you have "tried using ``os.walk`` but  it doesn't seem to work", please post an [mcve] of what you have tried and the details of how it doesn't work. If it does nothing, say so. If it throws an error, post the exact error message and the entire traceback. Also, since you mention dropbox: is the path actually mounted on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use os.walk and append only names which are in files.

```
from os import walk

file_names = list()
path = 'path/of/folder'

for root, dirc, files in walk(path):
    for FileName in files:
        file_names.append(FileName)

print(file_names)
```

This will append all the files name from all the directories and sub-directories of the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

this will create a list of the files in a folder

```
from os import listdir

# the path
path = ''

fileList = listdir(path)
```

Comment: ``listdir`` already creates a list. In general, the pattern ``[i for i in something]`` should be avoided, if only to prefer ``list(something)`` instead.